# Are there any standards similar to WSDL but designed for Java or C/C++?

Tags: xml, wsdl, standards

Are there any standards similar to WSDL but designed for Java or C/C++?

To be clear: I am designing an offline API, *not* a web service.

I am designing a system that allows different components to be plugged in,  but for the orchestrator to know how to call it I currently allow the orchestrator to retrieve back a sort of "get features" from the component. This "Get features" is just an XML that describes the (known) API calls it has support for or has implemented.

I'd like the ability to take it one step further and get back a description of the interface itself. The WSDL design would be perfect, but I was thinking there might be something out there that was designed for offline applications instead of "web services."

Thanks,
Chenz

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [IDLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language)? It's a bit dated, but it may be useful to you.